# Would these two transistors have the same Beta?

Tags: bjt, circuit-design

[image]

If both Q2 and Q1 are 2N3904 BJT transistors, can we assume that they share the same Beta?

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: It depends on what  you mean. For a first approximation, yes, you can assume they are the same. But you don't want to design your circuit so that it relies on the betas being exactly the same. Also, beta has a dependency on collector current. So even if they are very well matched, the betas may not be the same if they have different collector currents.

Comment: Did they teach you the concept of manufacturing variability?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to say without component values.  The Beta will vary as a function of collector current.  If their collector currents are the same they would have the same nominal Beta.  Beta has a pretty wide range around the nominal.  If their bias currents are different, then they would have a different nominal Betas.  The data sheet will have a graph that shows the nominal Beta as a function of collector current.

[image: 2n3904 beta]
To answer your question, the beta of a transistor also varies this temperature, which you can see in the graph, and with Vce.

Comment: Is Beta solely dependent on the collector current? I thought the collector current was determined by Beta ( Ic = Beta * Ib ) ?

Comment: I've updated the answer to show how Beta of the 2n3904 varies.  You are correct Ic=B*Ib.  Typically when you design with transistors the specifications will lead the choice of Ic.  Then the Beta at this current would be used to bias the thing.

Answer (score 1):

## You can do this for analysis' sake, but don't count on it for your circuit to work!

Transistor beta is highly variable from unit-to-unit, which is why circuits that depend on transistor beta as a parameter are not used when designing with discrete parts.

In general, you'll see a minimum beta spec for a few given operating points, and perhaps a typical or maximum beta for one or two of those conditions, as well as a "typical" beta vs Ic curve if the datasheet provides characteristic curves.

For the sake of circuit analysis though, a beta is needed, and the minimum for your circuit's operating point can safely be assumed (otherwise the transistor is out of spec and should be rubbish binned!).  If you want to be thorough, an analysis at maximum beta could be conducted as well -- I wouldn't insist on it though, as with a proper bias network, if your circuit works with a transistor that's barely in beta spec, it'll work with any other transistor of that type.

Answer (score 1):

Unless two transistors are on the same silicon substrate, you should not expect the same beta (Hfe) from devices. The forward current gain also varies markedly with temperature and it's very difficult to keep two separate transistors at exactly the same temperature. Read this for information on BJT matched pairs: http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/MAT12.pdf

The schematic you show would not be sensitive to differences in beta between the two transistor devices. The first device is a Common Base amplifier and the second an Emitter follower. 
If you look at the datasheet for your devices: http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/2N3903-D.PDF
I'd suggest your amplifier stage design should be based on a minimum Hfe about 40 and IC of 1-2mA.